# Is it possible to define a function on a subset of an existing type?

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and would like to know whether it's possible to define a function that is only defined on a subset of an already existing type, without actually having to define a new type.

Example: I want to create a function that only accepts even integers (or even natural numbers, etc.) and returns, e.g. that number squared, like:

```
squared :: 2*Integer -> Integer
squared n = n*n
```

The above two lines do not work, of course.

I know I could write it like this:

```
squared' :: Integer -> Integer
squared' n 
  | (even n) = n*n
  | otherwise = error "n is not even!"
```

or something similar, but I want to know whether something like the non-working example is possible, as well.

I hope this question is not completely stupid (or was already answered) but I really don't know a lot of Haskell yet (so searching for an answer was kind of difficult as well)...

Comment: it is not easy in Haskell

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general no. Such a thing is called a subset type, it's a hallmark of dependent types which Haskell doesn't have. Usually it's implemented by boxing a value with a proof that the value satisfies some property, but since we have no notion of proofs in Haskell, we're stuck.

Usually the way to fake it is with "smart constructors".

```
newtype Even = Even {unEven :: Integer} deriving (Eq, Show, Ord)

toEven :: Integer -> Maybe Even
toEven a | even a = Just $ Even a
         | otherwise = Nothing
```

And then hide the `Even` constructor.

If you really really want it, you can switch to a language that can interop with Haskell that has dependent types (Coq and Agda spring to mind).

Comment: Hooray for dependent types! If the concept of dependent types is a little confusing, check out this video: http://vimeo.com/77168227. It provides a nice example of using the dependent types to provide extra information such as length of lists etc. all at type level.

Answer (score 6):

No.  The type system would need to support refinement types (or full dependent types, as suggested by @jozefg).

Here is a Haskell extension with refinement types.

http://goto.ucsd.edu/~rjhala/liquid/haskell/blog/blog/2013/01/01/refinement-types-101.lhs/

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the subset in a newtype

```
newtype EvenInteger = EvenInteger {
    unEvenInteger :: Integer
} deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Num)

mkEvenInteger :: Integer -> Maybe EvenInteger
mkEvenInteger n = case n % 2 of
    0 -> Just $ EvenInteger n
    _ -> Nothing

squared :: EvenInteger -> EvenInteger
squared n = n * n
```

Comment: This doesn't work, `1 :: EvenInteger` injects 1 into the realm of even numbers

Comment: Erg... you're right. If one is willing to deal with syntactic ugliness, this solution could work without deriving `Num`. This would be one case where I'd say the cure is worse than the disease though :(

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be

```
newtype Even n = Even n
getEven (Even n) = 2*n

squared :: Num n => Even n -> Even n
squared (Even n) = Even (2*n*n)
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned elsewhere, refinement types like in LiquidHaskell can express this. Here's what it looks like:

```
module Evens where

{-@ type Even = {v:Int | v mod 2 = 0} @-}

{-@ square :: Even -> Int @-}
square :: Int -> Int
square n = n * n

-- calling the function:
yup = square 4
-- nope = square 3 -- will not compile if this is uncommented
```

You can try this out by plugging it in here: http://goto.ucsd.edu:8090/index.html