# Dependence of a function domain to the elements of another set in Haskell/Scala

Tags: scala, haskell

I would like to define a tuple `(A, f)`, such that A is a set of Integers and f is a function from this set to Integers. I would like to emphasize that f's domain is dependent on the A elements. For example, if A is defined to be `A={1,2}`, then `f={1->10,2->15}` is a valid instance of f, but `f={1->10,2->15,3->20}` is not a valid f; since in the second case f's domain is not restricted to A.

**My question:**

Is there any way to define `(A, f)` in Haskell/Scala such that dependability of f to A content is enforced by Haskell/Scala typing system. (I suspect that this scenario is an example of [dependent types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type). Am I right?)

---

**Update:**

I am adding a piece of Scala code for the above question, to add more clarity. Having the following code, the very concrete question would be: Is there any way (using typing system of the language) that make us free of writing the throw statement in the following code? that is to say, using language typing system, we say domain of f is restricted only to A elements?

```
class ClassA (val A:Set[Int], val f:Map[Int,Int] ){
    if (!A.equals(f.keySet)){
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("f domain and set A do not match")
     }
  }
```

Comment: So do you just want an `i -> b` function where `i` is the type of a subset of integers, and thus the question boils down to "how can we define a type containing a subset of integers"?

Comment: @AndrásKovács I believe the OP wouldn't want to define a new type for each instance of such a tuple..

Comment: @András Kovács, I want `i` to be an specific subset of integers that is defined in runtime (that is, user instantiate A, and I want f to be a function from this specific A to integers). In other words, as @Eugene mentioned, I do not want to define a new type for each specific  `i`; rather,  I want to define f more generally representing a set of types from the sets of integers ( defined by user in runtime) to integers. I hope this clarifies more the question.

Comment: It does, but you can't define A in Haskell.

Comment: @Rein, would you please elaborate a bit.

Comment: You can't define a type as a subset of another type in Haskell.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs I think we can, for most types.

Comment: @AndrásKovács Can it be an *infinite* subset?

Comment: BTW, found [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730031/is-it-possible-to-define-a-function-on-a-subset-of-an-existing-type). Not sure if it is duplicate.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit on how you plan to use this?  What is known at runtime and compile time?  How do you want to enforce the domain restriction – a compile-time error?  a run-time exception?

Comment: @Ben, I think it should be run-time error, since in compile-time, the elements of A is not yet initialized.

Comment: Practical answer: use [`Map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#t:Map). The theoretical answer has so very much more boilerplate...

Comment: @DanielWagner, I do not think using Maps will be the solution, we need to check the key set of map f to be restricted to the A contents by some extra coding. It seems having this extra coding is inevitable in Scala/Haskell. I will update the question with Scala code.

Comment: In the Scala case, I think if it's possible, then the solution will involve something like what Shapeless does.

Comment: @qartal Don't keep a separate set and map. _Just_ the map. The set is implicit: the keys that exist in the map define the set.

Comment: I don't get it -- all you want is a run-time error, yet you want the constraint "enforced by Haskell/Scala typing system". If you really want the check at run-time, why bothering with the type system and its enforcement at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this in Scala by leveraging the following -

- The [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) library to encode integers as `Nat` values (natural numbers)
- An object `f` with an `apply()` method to emulate a function call
- A type class `F[N]` defined in that object which enforces the acceptable input types

```scala
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import shapeless._

object f {
  def apply(n: Nat)(implicit ev: F[n.N]) = ev()
  sealed trait F[N] { def apply(): Int }
  private def inst[N](r: Int): F[N] = new F[N] { def apply(): Int = r }
  implicit val one = inst[Nat._1](10)
  implicit val two = inst[Nat._2](15)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import shapeless._
defined object f

scala> f(1)
res0: Int = 10

scala> f(2)
res1: Int = 15

scala> f(3)
<console>:16: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: f.F[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]]]]
       f(3)
        ^
```