# What is the F# equivalent of string.IsNullOrEmpty()?

Tags: f#

Given the following record in F#:

```
type Model =
   { Text: string option }
```

What is the F# equivalent of  C#'s,

```
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Text)
```

TIA

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42427189/f-type-alias-for-non-nullable-string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want to treat a `None` value as null or empty you can use `Option.fold`:

```
let m = { Text = Some "label" }
m.Text |> Option.fold (fun _ s -> String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) true
```

a drawback of using `fold` is the ignored accumulator parameter in the accumulator function. In this case you just need a function to apply in the case of `Some` and a default value to use if the option is `None` e.g.

```
let getOr ifNone f = function
    | None -> ifNone
    | Some(x) -> f x
```

then you can use

```
m.Text |> getOr true String.IsNullOrEmpty
```

Comment: I've worked a lot in F# and never seen `Option.fold` used so I don't think it's idiomatic. This is a bit confusing for me. I have to stare at it for a while to know exactly what it's doing.

Comment: ok, but it is quite idiomatic of functional programming in general, "fold" (and unfold) is a basic building block of almost all non trivial algorirhtms. I just think...its an array/seq/list with 1 or 0 elements in it.

Comment: Your `getOr` function almost exists already, albeit with inverse argument order; `defaultArg (m.Text |> Option.map String.IsNullOrEmpty) true`

Comment: It's a  bit of an old topic but I'm new at F# and I'm getting the error "The type 'string' does not match the type 'string option'" for both of your suggestions. It baffles me why I can't just do `let result = if string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) then foo else bar`. How do I express this?

Comment: @Diana - What's the type of `s` in your code? It sounds like it's a `string`, in which case you should be able to call `String.IsNullOrEmpty` directly, and your example should work.

Comment: @Lee s comes from `let s = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BLA")` which should be `string` according to intellisense but I get this error regardless

Answer (score 5):

Lees answer is probably the most functionally idiomatic i.e. when you want to process a data type, you can squash it into an answer using fold. But note that you can drop the "s", to make it

```
m.Text |> Option.fold (fun _ -> String.IsNullOrEmpty) true
```

if folding isnt something that you are yet at ease with then a more set oriented version would be, "are all of them empty?" (if there are none, then they are)

```
m.Text |> Option.forall (fun s -> String.IsNullOrEmpty s)
```

or in short hand

```
m.Text |> Option.forall String.IsNullOrEmpty
```

(I'd personally use this one)

Answer (score 2):

The `Option.toObj` function converts an option containing a reference type to a nullable object. A `None` will be converted to `null`. It's quite useful for interop with APIs expecting nulls:

```ml
model.Text |> Option.toObj |> String.IsNullOrEmpty
```